# if statements in C# for a textbox to change back to normal when i press a button for the second time

Tags: c#

This is the code that i used to change the text in the text box from "Livre" to "Ocupado"
What code should i use to change it from "Ocupado" to "Livre"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text="Ocupado";
}
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text = "Livre";` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "Livre")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Ocupado";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Livre";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a variable to your class

e.g.:

```
bool livre = true;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (livre)
    {
        textBox1.Text="Ocupado";
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text="Livre";
    }
    livre = !livre;     
}
```