# How do I only use one button for this?

Tags: c#, .net, button

Alright, so I'm trying to practice my windows forms skills and I've been trying to figure out a simple thing such as making a button that says "Show message", when you click it, it makes an invisible label Visible that says "Hey man" and the text of the button should change to "Hide message".

When you click it the label should go invisible again. I tried to do it with if statements for a while but didn't really figure it out, so I just used 2 buttons which made it a million times more simple. I'm just wondering, how would I go about doing it with only 1 button?

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblShow.Visible = true;
            btnShow.Visible = false;
            btnHide.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblShow.Visible = false;
            btnShow.Visible = true;
            btnHide.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a bool variable to your class and toggle the value like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040191/if-statements-in-c-sharp-for-a-textbox-to-change-back-to-normal-when-i-press-a-b

Answer (score 1):

You could add a bool to your class, and change the bool when you click the button

```
bool showLabel = true;

private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (showLabel)
    {
        lblShow.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblShow.Visible = false;
    }
    showLabel = !showLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite simply with only two lines of code:

```
private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblShow.Visible = !lblShow.Visible;
    btnToggle.Text = lblShow.Visible ? "Hide Message" : "Show Message";
}
```

It can technically be done in one line, but I think it's less readable:

```
btnToggle.Text = (lblShow.Visible = !lblShow.Visible) ? "Hide Message" : "Show Message";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor using one method to set the label visibility like that:

```
private void btnToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblShow.Visible = !lblShow.Visible;
  btnToggle.Text = lblShow.Visible ? "Hide Message" : "Show Message";
}
```

With the VS Form Desiner you can set the label Visible property to true and the button Text to nothing.

And in the FormLoad event you call the method to set the things :

```
btnToggle_Click(this, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping a state variable and updating the form based on the value of the state variable. This is a flexible pattern where you can accommodate more than one state, which means you can have combinations of buttons that produce different results.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public enum FormState
    {
        MessageHidden,
        MessageVisible,
        Default = MessageHidden
    }

    FormState state = FormState.Default;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        UpdateUI();
    }
    protected void UpdateUI()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case FormState.MessageHidden:
                label1.Visible = false;
                button1.Text = "Show Message";
                break;
            case FormState.MessageVisible:
                label1.Visible = true;
                button1.Text = "Hide Message";
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case FormState.MessageHidden:
                state = FormState.MessageVisible;
                break;
            case FormState.MessageVisible:
                state = FormState.MessageHidden;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        UpdateUI();
    }
}
```

Example screenshots

- **`FormState.MessageHidden`**

[image: pic1]

- **`FormState.MessageVisible`**

[image: pic2]